# Has someone ever proposed a "many worlds/histories" model where all possible boundary conditions are considered?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, theoretical-physics, cosmology

The Hawking-Hartle no boundary condition is a well known model that tries to explain how did the universe begin. The authors considered a "many worlds/histories" model considering a sum over all compact euclidean metrics.

But are there any models or theories that consider a sum over all possible metrics or boundaries? Have any physicists ever proposed such model or theory?